Is the AUC Baseline always 0.5?
I have a model where I'm deadling with about 72% of cases being positive and the other 28% being negitive. So when making a baseline if I randomly assign every case to be positive isn't the baseline instead .72*.72+.28*.28=0.5968? I guess I'm thinking of accuracy, but I'm not sure how to think of it as AUC of true positive rate (i'm positive with 72% accuracy, 72% of time) vs false positive rate or am I thinking of it correctly?

Yes, the AUC baseline is always $0.5$.
You can think of the AUC as the probability of ranking a random positive instance higher than a random negative instance. One of the advantages of AUC is that the proportion of positives or negatives in the data doesn't matter; the range of possible AUC values is still 0.5 to 1.
Note that the AUC is calculated from a ordered ranking, not just from a prediction of whether each case is positive or negative. You have to have a model which outputs something like, for example, the probability of being in the positive class in order to construct an ROC curve. If your model doesn't give you a ranking of your cases, you can't calculate an AUC from it.
